# How to capture exceptions from custom class library called within a script task?

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I have created a class Library in VB.NET which we are calling from SSIS script task.

Could someone please advice how I can throw error back from VB.NET function which was suppose to return a string value but it returns `null`, in that case I would like the SSIS script task to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to fail the package if any exception / Null thrown from your function library. Replace YourMethodCall() to your method.

#### C#:

```
// For General exceptions
try
{
    // Your Method call
    var x = YourMethodCall();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
    {
        Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Your component Name", "Your Error Message", string.Empty, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        bool isFireAgain = false;
        Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "You component Name", "Your Information for Successful run", string.Empty, 0, ref isFireAgain);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Your component Name", String.Format("Failed and Exception is : [{0}]",ex.Message), string.Empty, 0);
}
```

Hope this helps!